# How can I Determine If a Page Overflows into Additional Page with XSL-FO?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have a `xsl:for-each` that recursively adds `fo:table` elements. Before `xsl:for-each` I have a "title" block.

What I'm wondering is if I can determine if the table overflows into another page and allow me to "inject" the title block again. This way I can indicate the previous table has continued.

```
-> Page 1
--> The Title
---> Table
-> Page 2
--> The Title (cont.)
---> Remaining Table
```

**UPDATE**

Taking [Mathias Müller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1987598/mathias-m%C3%BCller)'s suggestion and attempting to use a `fo:table-header` FOP 2.1 supports a `fo:retrieve-table-marker` which should allow for "continued" headers. However, the continuation doesn't seem to work plus now the body is overlapping the header.

```
<xsl:for-each select="results/group">
    <fo:block>

        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
            <fo:table-column column-width="1.8in"/>
            <fo:table-column />
            <fo:table-column />
            <fo:table-column />
            <fo:table-column />
            <fo:table-column />
            <fo:table-column />
            <fo:table-header>
                <fo:table-row background-color="cmyk(0.72, 0.17, 0.03, 0.04)" color="#FFFFFF" font-size="15pt">
                    <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="7">
                        <fo:block padding="1mm" text-indent="0.3em">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$title" />
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <xsl:call-template name="result_table_header" />
            </fo:table-header>
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row font-size="9pt">
                    <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="7">
                        <fo:block>
                            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-collapse="separate">
                                <fo:table-column column-width="1.8in" />
                                <fo:table-column />
                                <fo:table-column />
                                <fo:table-column />
                                <fo:table-column />
                                <fo:table-column />
                                <fo:table-column />
                                <fo:table-body>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="result">
                                        <xsl:call-template name="result_row" />
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </fo:table-body>
                            </fo:table>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>

    </fo:block>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**UPDATE #2**

I fixed the overlapping, but I had to take out the `fo:marker`. It was not adding the "(cont.)".

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13922082/how-to-make-xsl-fo-table-caption-repeat-on-each-page-when-the-table-spans-multip

Comment: What exactly is the title block, i.e. in which FO elements is it? Can you put it into `fo:table-header`?

Comment: Title is just an `fo:block` containing a title. Yes similar to a table header.

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen do you know if this possible with FOP?

Comment: Your update has an error. "It is an error if two or more fo:markers that share the same parent have the same "marker-class-name" property value." (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_marker)

Comment: @TonyGraham you're right. I guess I'm having a hard time comprehending these markers. One example, I found they had both markers named that same and other examples they did not. Regardless, still not working even with different class names.

Comment: Your explanation and code don;t seem to match. you seem to say you have many tables (I recursively add fo:table ...). Yet you show only one in your sample. Is your issue that you have many tables and want to repeat the heading before them (whether they split or not ) or you have a heading above *one* table?

Comment: @KevinBrown I omitted the wrapping `<xsl:for-each>` and `<fo:block>` I thought it was clear in the explanation and I try not to write these questions with code content where it leads to TL;DR; If I were to include all my code you would have a hundred lines or so that are irrelevant to the region I'm focused on. Apologies.

Comment: I was only asking if it is title followed by one table .... or is it title followed by many tables. The wording seems to indicate you can have many tables  (you say you do a for-each that adds "tables")

Comment: I updated the example. I did more the `xsl:call-template` to the `fo:table-header` now it's a question getting the marker to work.

Answer (score -1):

These work with AH Formatter V6.3.

There's the 'fake the title in the header' technique:

```
  <fo:table table-layout="auto" width="100%">
     <fo:table-column column-width="1.8in" />
     <fo:table-column />
     <fo:table-column />
     <fo:table-column />
     <fo:table-column />
     <fo:table-column />
     <fo:table-column />
     <fo:table-header>
        <fo:table-row background-color="cmyk(0.72, 0.17, 0.03, 0.04)" color="#FFFFFF" font-size="15pt">
           <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="7" padding-bottom="6pt">
              <fo:block padding="1mm" text-indent="0.3em">
                 <fo:retrieve-table-marker retrieve-class-name="header-continued" retrieve-boundary-within-table="table" />
              </fo:block>
           </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-row>
           <fo:table-cell><fo:block>h</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
           <fo:table-cell><fo:block>The real table header</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
           <fo:table-cell />
           <fo:table-cell />
           <fo:table-cell />
           <fo:table-cell />
           <fo:table-cell />
        </fo:table-row>
     </fo:table-header>
     <fo:table-body>
        <fo:table-row>
           <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="7"><fo:marker marker-class-name="header-continued">Title</fo:marker></fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-row font-size="9pt">
            <fo:marker marker-class-name="header-continued">Title (Cont)</fo:marker>
           <fo:table-cell><fo:block>Lorem ipsum...</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
           <fo:table-cell />
           <fo:table-cell />
           <fo:table-cell />
           <fo:table-cell />
           <fo:table-cell />
           <fo:table-cell />
        </fo:table-row>
     </fo:table-body>
  </fo:table>
```

and the 'nested tables' technique (as you tried):

```
  <fo:table table-layout="auto" width="100%" break-before="page">
     <fo:table-header>
        <fo:table-row background-color="cmyk(0.72, 0.17, 0.03, 0.04)" color="#FFFFFF" font-size="15pt">
           <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="7" padding-bottom="6pt">
              <fo:block padding="1mm" text-indent="0.3em">
                 <fo:retrieve-table-marker retrieve-class-name="header-continued"
                    retrieve-boundary-within-table="table"/>
              </fo:block>
           </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
     </fo:table-header>
     <fo:table-body>
        <fo:table-row>
           <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="7"><fo:marker marker-class-name="header-continued">Title</fo:marker></fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-row font-size="9pt">
           <fo:table-cell>
              <fo:marker marker-class-name="header-continued">Title (Cont)</fo:marker>
                 <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-collapse="separate">
                    <fo:table-header>
                       <fo:table-row>
                          <fo:table-cell><fo:block>h</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                          <fo:table-cell><fo:block>The real table header</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                          <fo:table-cell />
                          <fo:table-cell />
                          <fo:table-cell />
                          <fo:table-cell />
                          <fo:table-cell />
                       </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-header>
                    <fo:table-body>
                       <fo:table-row>
                          <fo:table-cell><fo:block>Lorem ipsum...</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                          <fo:table-cell></fo:table-cell>
                          <fo:table-cell></fo:table-cell>
                          <fo:table-cell></fo:table-cell>
                          <fo:table-cell></fo:table-cell>
                          <fo:table-cell></fo:table-cell>
                          <fo:table-cell></fo:table-cell>
                       </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-body>
                 </fo:table>
           </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
     </fo:table-body>
  </fo:table>
```